# What's a word for a group of questions asked together?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, questions

Is there a word for a set of questions that are asked together and are related? For example, one asks the question:

> Do you go rafting?

And follow up with:

> If yes, where? 
>    If no, what do you do instead?

I'd like a word that represents this collection of questions, some of which are meaningless outside of their grouping. Is there such a word?

I have a couple of ideas in mind ([linked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inquiry) [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_%28language_use%29) so I can limit influencing your opinion).

I'm looking for something much smaller than an interview (which is a larger collection of loosely-related questions), and different from a page (which is a physical arrangement of questions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few options, some admittedly phrases and also various forms:

- line of questioning
- questions
- questioning
- questionnaire
- a grilling
- investigation
- review
- debriefing
- interrogation
- poll
- survey

Answer (score 3):

Since your questions depend on previous questions a [Decision Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree) comes to my mind.

- [another resource](http://gautam.lis.illinois.edu/monkmiddleware/public/analytics/decisiontree.html)

Answer (score 3):

A quick succession of many questions might be described as a *barrage of questions*, though that does have the implication that they came a little too fast for comfort.

Answer (score 2):

If your focus is on the sequence of questions that the asker must follow, you might use *script*.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be an 'inquiry' (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inquiry):

> in·quir·y   /ɪnˈkwaɪəri, ˈɪnkwəri/
>
> 1 -  a seeking or request for truth, information, or knowledge.
>
> 2 - an investigation, as into an incident: a Congressional inquiry into
> the bribery charges.
>
> 3 - the act of inquiring or of seeking information by questioning;
> interrogation.
>
> 4 - a question; query.

Comment: Please provide the name of where you got these copy-pasted citations from, and a link if available.  See the meta question on [What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion about this.

Answer (score 2):

The word 'battery' comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to convey the idea of a high throughput of questions, here are a few suggestions (many inspired by weather related metaphors).

- A "burst" of questions
- A "gust" of questions
- A "hail" of questions
- A "flurry" of questions
- A "rain" of questions